# Codename One - BrowserComponent: force page loading in a given language

Tags: codenameone

Some multilingual websites serve pages in several languages, according to the browser language. Can I force BrowserComponent to ask pages in a given language (that can be equal or different from the O.S. language)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this refers to setting the language in the browser which isn't something we expose at this time. It's something you can ask for via RFE. If you are aiming at a specific site that stores the data via a cookie you can probably set that via the [JavaScript bridge](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/javascript/package-summary.html).